# Is there any possible way to get these hearts as Adult Link?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time-3d

I'm playing this game and I didn't get the hearts outside Zora's domain before becoming Adult Link. [image: One of the hearts]

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can, but even if you can't, you can go back to child in the temple of time by putting the master sword back. Nothing becomes missable simply by becoming adult

Comment: @Unionhawk To add to that, there are no missable collectables in this game, period.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, collecting this Piece of Heart is possible as an adult, and very simple too. All you need is the [**Hover Boots**](https://zelda.gamepedia.com/Hover_Boots) found in the [**Shadow Temple**](https://zelda.gamepedia.com/Shadow_Temple) of Kakariko.

However, by the time you can enter the Shadow Temple, you'll already have been granted the ability to turn back into a child. This means you could just grab a Cucco and get the piece before completing either the Bottom of the Well, or finding the Hover Boots in the Shadow Temple.

The choice is yours.

Comment: what does completing the Bottom of the Well have to do with this?

Comment: @IvoBeckers. It's to get the Eye of Truth, which is a prerequisite to complete the Shadow Temple. I'm not sure if you can get the Hover Boots without it, but if you're following a walkthrough, you're pretty much guaranteed to complete the Bottom of the Well before entering the Shadow Temple.

Comment: The point is that you can turn back to a child as soon as you finish the forest temple, so the reference to the shadow temple is a bit of a red herring (although it's the earliest you actually _need_ to turn back in a normal playthrough).

Comment: @Cubic. I think you misunderstand. The Shadow Temple is the earliest you can get this Piece of Heart *as adult Link*, not after pulling the Master Sword.

Comment: Can't you collect heart pieces as adult using the hookshot/longshot? And as child using the boomerang? If so, there is no need for a cuccoo or the hover boots.

Comment: @Ian that would make things too easy.

Comment: @Ian No, the hookshot doesn't fetch heart pieces.

Comment: @Ian You're not crazy, though—the hookshot *does* fetch heart pieces in some other Zelda games, but not in OOT.

Comment: It’s been a long time, but I’m about 90% sure you can get the Hover Boots without the Lens of Truth. I know they’re in the first section of the Shadow Temple, and while you’re “supposed” to use the Lens of Truth to reveal the Dead Hand who’s guarding them, I’m pretty sure if you know where the door is you can just ignore the illusory wall and open up the door to get them.

Comment: @KRyan This is true—the Lens of Truth isn't required for anything in the game.

Comment: It's worth noting that, with a precise jump, it's possible to get this heart piece as adult without hover boots: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXxvf0IgmhQ (the video shows it on the N64 version, but a similar jump is likely possible on the 3DS version as well)